# Rails Devise guest users tokens

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, record

There is a Rails hotel list app with Devise/CanCan set up

```
class HotelsController < ApplicationController
before_filter :authenticate_user!, except: [:show]
load_and_authorize_resource
```

1) What is the most elegant way to let owners edit their hotel info without registering them as users?

2) What if we create a unique token for every hotel and email something like the following link to the corresponding owner:

http://myapp.io/hotels/10010/edit?token=AAAABBBBCCCCDDD

..how to configure Devise/CanCan so they authenticate the user and allow them edit the corresponding record in the Hotels table?

Thank you in advance!

Regards,
Serge.

Answer (score 0):

A quick and dirty solution would be to override the `authenticate_user!` method and add a check for the token:

```
# application_controller.rb
def authenticate_user!
  if (token = params[:token] || session[:token])
    @current_user = User.find_by_token token
    session[:token] = token if @current_user
  else
    super
  end
end
```

First you'd have to add the token column to the user table and you'd still need to create a user for them. Generate a token and email them the link with their token. When they first arrive at the site with the token in the URL, the above method will check if there's a matching record in the db and set it as the `current_user` and save the token to the session so that subsequent requests will still work. Don't forget to clear that session later (logout or expires).

The reason you still need to create a user record is that you don't want to start overriding your cancan logic and you need a place to store the token anyway.

There's also some gems that will add token authentication:

https://github.com/gonzalo-bulnes/simple_token_authentication

And a simple Rails built in solution:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/HttpAuthentication/Token.html